# Chinese language support for Raspbmc

Tags: raspbmc

I can't see any files whose names are composed entirely of Chinese characters on my Raspbmc menus. If there is a mixutre of Chinese and ASCII characters, I can see only the ASCII characters in the file name. I've searched but I can't find any information about how to enable Chinese language support.

Comment: It's not really a pi specific question, you might have better luck with this on unix/linux SE. Perhaps ask to have it migrated.  Raspbmc is a minimal Debian Distribution.

Comment: Raspbmc is based on debian, so why not just pull language support from there? https://packages.debian.org/stable/localization/

Comment: It's not a problem with Debian's filesystem. It's a problem with the menus used to select media files. The XBMC interface is lacking Chinese support and I'm not sure how to enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://immigrationroad.com/blog/how-to-watch-chinese-tv-online-using-xbmc/ :

**Display XBMC Menus in Chinese**

To make XBMC display Chinese characters correctly, you will need to install fonts and change several settings.

- Go to XBMC.org and download the font: [DejaVuSans+DriodSansFallback.ttf](http://trac.xbmc.org/attachment/ticket/6397/DejaVuSans%2BDriodSansFallback.ttf);
- Change the file name to arial.ttf;
- Go to (your XBMC installation folder)/XBMC/media/Fonts/. For example, it may be C:/Program Files/XBMC/media/Fonts/;
- There should be a file already called arial.ttf. Change the file name to something like arial-original in case you will need it later on;
- Now copy and paste your downloaded arial.ttf to the Fonts folder;
- Go to XBMC – Home – System – Settings – Appearance;
- Under Skin – Fonts, click the up/down arrow to change the setting to “Arial based”;
- Under International – Language, click the up/down arrow to select Chinese (Simple);
- Under International – Character Set, click the up/down arrow to select Chinese Simplified (GBK);
- Your XBMC should now be displaying Chinese characters properly;

This worked for me but I changed the font directory to `/usr/share/fonts/truetype`.